# get error "account is locked" for system in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i try to log on to Oracle SQL Developer using account "system", i get the following errors,

ORA-28000: the account is locked,

But i can log on to SQL Plus using "system",

what's the reason for that error ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you log onto the same database?

Comment: what's that mean ? and how to confirm i log onto the same database ?

Answer (score 2):

in cmd:
sqlplus \sys as sysdba,
your password,
alter user SYSTEM account unlock;